# What is the standard way to get the state of a C++0x random number generator?

Tags: c++, random, c++11

I am trying to learn the new C++0x approach to random number generators (26.5), and implement at C++0x-compliant random number engine (26.5.1.4).

The standard goes into detail on the required interface for seed sequences, and how they can be passed to the constructor or `seed` functions of engines.

However, I cannot find any standard interface to create or generate a seed sequence from an engine, thereby getting its internal state. Is there one? Or can states only be copied between engines via copy-construction/assignment or copying the initial seed sequence?

If it's not possible, does anyone know what the rationale is (if any) for not providing such an interface?

Comment: This assumes that any state can be achieved via a seed sequence. Is that a correct assumption to start with?

Comment: @MSalters: I think so, or at least I think it would not be an onerous restriction. The internal state of any computation is representable as a series of integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no API for generating a seed or seed sequence from an engine's state.  However the engine's state can be streamed into an istream, and extracted from an ostream.  And the engine's state is EqualityComparable to another engine's state (for same-type engines).

One might inspect the istream generated by streaming an engine to it.  However the format of that istream is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

That's my understanding as well. (To be clear: I think that states can only be copied between engines via copy-construction/assignment or constructing with the same initial seed sequence and having generated the same number of pseudo-random numbers.)

Answer (score 0):

The internal state doesn't have to look anything like the seed sequence. I think this is close to asking the compiler for the source code from a binary. Not possible.

You can copy the entire engine though, and have the copy regenerate the same sequence once more. Or you can stream the state to a file, and reload it again.

Comment: _The internal state doesn't have to look anything like the seed sequence._ However, since the seed sequence has no standard effect on an engine other than to initialize its internal state, there seems to be no reason for the standard not to require it. Extensive munging of the seed sequence to establish your state doesn't really gain you anything.

Comment: @Joe : Perhaps not, but that is exactly what the standard requires most of the engines to do. The engine establishes its state from the parameters of the seed sequence, it does not just store the sequence.

Comment: Simply generating n elements of the seed sequence and copying each into your internal state, as every RNG I am aware of (which, granted, is certainly not all!) does, does not preclude regenerating the sequence. In fact it means it's trivial to do so - just copy your internal state back out. I cannot think of a case in which irreversible munging of the seed sequence presents a benefit.