# How to Save State of C++0X Random Number Generator

Tags: random, c++11

I'm playing around with the new C++0X random library and based on this question:
[What is the standard way to get the state of a C++0x random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142069/what-is-the-standard-way-to-get-the-state-of-a-c0x-random-number-generator)
it seems that if you don't know the seed for the current state of a random generator, the only way to save its state is by storing the generator in a stream.  To do this I wrote the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/)
{
  std::mt19937 engine1;
  unsigned int var = engine1(); // Just to get engine1 out of its initial state
  std::stringstream input;
  input << engine1;
  std::mt19937 engine2;
  input >> engine2;
  std::cout<<"Engine comparison: "<<(engine1 == engine2)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Engine 1 random number "<<engine1()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Engine 2 random number "<<engine2()<<std::endl;
}
```

This outputs

> Engine comparison: 1
>   Engine 1 random number 581869302
>   Engine 2 random number 4178893912

I have a few questions:

- Why are the next numbers from engine1 and engine2 different?
- Why are the two engines comparing equal even though their next numbers are different?
- What am I doing wrong in my example and what is the correct way to save the state of a random engine to get repeatability in later runs (assuming you don't know the seed to set the desired state)?

Thank you.

Comment: Note in [Wikipedia's pseudo-code for the Marsenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) that an array of length `624` is created to store the PRNG's state; this is one reason why its period is 2^19937 − 1 rather than 2^32 or shorter, if it exposed the entire state in each output.

Comment: I get the same result in gcc 4.6, but it is fixed in gcc 4.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me.  I ran your code on [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) and the output is:

```
Engine comparison: 1
Engine 1 random number 581869302
Engine 2 random number 581869302
```

Comment: Of course I should point out that this implementation usually outputs 581869302 (http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/) :-)

Comment: Thank you for the link :).  I'll probably switch to the troll random number generator given my repeatability requirements.